# How to write valid regex groups?

Tags: java, regex

I try to write regex in order to validate that :

- not lowercase characters
- not only whitespace

I have write a regex `(^[^a-z]+$)(^[^ ]+$)` but when i test it, `SFSFSD`is incorrect.

How can i do that ?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
^[^a-z]*[^a-z\s][^a-z]*$
```

This would assert that there be at least one non whitespace, non lowercase letter, character, with the remaining being either whitespace or non lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the regex `(^(?!\\s+$)[^a-z]+)`

- `(?!\\s+$)` part checks if the regex does not contain only whitespaces till the end
- `[^a-z]+` then check for the lowercase characters

Tested with a few samples:

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList("   ", "SFSFSD", "as DDdkj", "AB CD", "    k", "l  l");
String regex = "(^(?!\\s+$)[^a-z]+)";
for(String word : wordList) {
    if(word.matches(regex)) {
        System.out.println(word + " :valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println(word + " :not valid");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    :not valid
SFSFSD :valid
as DDdkj :not valid
AB CD :valid
     k :not valid
l    l :not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the regex to validate that:
`/^(?!^ +$)([^a-z]+)$/`

**Explanation**

- `^` matches the position before the first character in the string.
- `(?!^ +$)` negative lookahead, that matches if the string not only whitespace.
- `([^a-z]+)` matches all characters except lowercase characters.
- `$` matches the right after character position of the string.